# Python novice: Setting limits for multiple integers taken as input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that would take an input of 3 numbers (i, j & k) in a single line separated by spaces, with limits for each number being from 1 to 1000 (inclusive). I need some advice regarding how to set the limit for all three numbers at once. Thanks in advance! My buggy code is below:

```
i, j, k = input("Please input 3 numbers between 1 and 1000:").split()
i, j, k = int(i), int(j), int(k)

if i, j, k >1000 or i, j, k <1:
    print ("Please try again")

else:
    print ("Thank you!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python's `any()` and `all()` functions for testing conditions on large number of values. In your case it should look like

```
if all([1<=x<=1000 for x in [i,j,k]]):
    print ("Thank you!")
else:
    print ("Please try again")
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is much cleaner than the roundabout solution I found:
    if i <1 or j <1 or k < 1 or i > 1000 or j > 1000 or k> 1000:
        print ("Please try again")

    else:
        print (i*j*k*2)